# Обновление StringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

На форме есть StringGrid. По нажатию кнопки, добавляется строка, в которой заново генерируется массив.
Но нужно сделать, чтоб массив генерировался один раз, а потом по нажатию кнопки в каждой добавленной строке выводился этот же массив на каждой итерации сортировки.
Буду очень признателен, если подскажете, как реализовать.

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i : integer;
begin
  randomize;
   for i:=0 to 9 do
    begin
      a[i]:=random(50);
      strgrid.Cells[i,SG.RowCount-1]:= IntToStr(a[i]);
    end;
     strgrid.RowCount:= SG.RowCount +1;
     strgrid.Height:=  SG.Height +30;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure Sorting(var a:arrint);
var left, right, tmp, x: integer;
begin
  left:=L;
  right:=R;
  L:=low(a);
  R:=high(a);
  x:=a[(L+R) div 2];
  repeat
   while a[L] < x do
    inc(L);
   while a[R] > x do
    dec(R);
   if L <= R then
    begin
      tmp:=a[L];
      a[L]:=a[R];
      a[R]:=tmp;
      inc(L);
      dec(R);
    end;
     until L > R;
      if left < R then
       Sorting(a);
      if L < right then
         Sorting(a);

end;
begin
  Sorting(a);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Что конкретно вызывает трудности? Помимо, конечно, двух методов класса `TForm1` с абсолютно одинаковыми названиями `BitBtn1Click`.

Comment: @Igor, опечатка, там разные кнопки, одна создает массив, другая выводит на каждой итерации. Не понятно, как сделать этот вывод, описать в коде.

Comment: Это как? Можно какой то явный пример? > по нажатию кнопки в каждой добавленной строке выводился этот же массив на каждой итерации сортировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Уточнения**:

- `strgrid.RowCount:= SG.RowCount +1`;

у Вас есть 2 `TStringGrid'a`?

- `Sorting(var a:arrint);`

Разве тут не должен быть тип или `var a: array of Integer`?

- Вы работаете с массивом `a[i]:=random(50);` но хоть где то устанавливаете размер?
- `strgrid.RowCount:= SG.RowCount +1;`

А почему вы не увеличиваете количество колонок? `strgrid.ColCount := Length(a);`
У Вас же будет отображаться только одна ячейка, а заполнение идет колонок `strgrid.Cells[i, strgrid.RowCount - 1] := IntToStr(a[i]);`

**Ответы**:

> Но нужно сделать, чтоб массив генерировался один раз

Проверять, если `Length(a) > 0` - значит массив уже сгенерирован.

> по нажатию кнопки в каждой добавленной строке выводился этот же массив на каждой итерации сортировки.

Можно воспользоваться чем то таким (просто вызвать в нужном месте передав массив в виде параметра)

```
procedure TForm1.PrintArray(Arr...)
var
 i: integer;
begin
   for i:=0 to Length(Arr)-1 do
   begin
      strgrid.Cells[i, strgrid.RowCount-1]:= Arr[i];
   end;
   strgrid.RowCount := strgrid.RowCount + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а как мне сделать, чтоб при каждой итерации индексы элементов, которые нужно поменять местами в сортировке, можно было узнать у пользователя заново? 
Т.е. массив получили, указали правую, левую границы, поменяли местами, если по условию проходит; если же нет, выводим как есть массив, узнаем индексы заново и построчно выводим?

Comment: Вам нужно узнать L и R в какой то момент?

Comment: Да, если L и R удовлетворяют условию L > опорный, R < опорный, то поменять местами и вывести массив на данной итерации, если нет, попросить пользователя ввести L+1, R-1 и тд., пока массив не отсортирован.

Comment: Если L и R удовлетворяют условие - вызвать `PrintArray`. А вот если нет - переписать алгоритм таким образом чтобы пользователь смог ввести данные. В более новых версиях `Delphi` можно было воспользоваться анонимными методами для этого. Но все же раз у Вас логика и UI пересекаются - можете показать `inputBox`/`InputQuery` для введения L и R, Пример: `L := inputbox('Введите L', 'L value', IntToStr(L));`